# Printing Unicode in Java

Tags: java, unicode

I need to print Unicodes of A-Z in Java.

How do I print the Unicode of a character in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int CharCode = (int)'a';`

Or:

`System.out.println((int)'a');`

So for your example:

```
for (char c='A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
{
    System.out.println(c + ": " + (int)c);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`Character` class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the unicode numbers of the letters you can do the following (here for the letter 'x'):

```
byte[] bytes = "x".getBytes( "UTF-16" );

System.out.println( String.format("%0" + (bytes.length * 2) + "X", 
    new BigInteger( 1, bytes )) );
```

This will output:

```
FEFF0078
```

For UTF-8 and other letters simply change the first line.

Comment: I think I've never seen such a bloated and even incorrect implementation of `(int)'x'`.